# Retrievving eventTarget after addEventListener in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 input fields in an html document.

```
Username : <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><div id='use'></div>
Email : <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><div id='ema'></div>
```

And a javascript file.

```
window.onload = initialise;

function initialise() {
    username = document.getElementById('username');
    username.addEventListener('keyup', respond, false);
    email = document.getElementById('email');
    email.addEventListener('keyup', respond, false);
}

function respond() {
    //code
}
```

Is there any way in which I can know inside the respond() function whether it was the username field or the email field for which the respond() method is called?
Both procedural code and OOP is welcome thought procedural code is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, pass in `event` and use `event.target.id`

```
function respond(e) {
    //code
    var id = e.target.id; //id of called element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `this` provided that `respond` was not bounded to another context. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LV8ZX/).

```
function respond() {
    console.log(this.id);    
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

> It is often desirable to reference the element from which the event
>   handler was fired, such as when using a generic handler for a series
>   of similar elements. When attaching a function using
>   `addEventListener()` the value of `this` is changed—note that the value of
>   this is passed to a function from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

With tymeJV's answer and a correction in your code, I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5EGB/) for you.

HTML:

```
Username : <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><div id='use'></div>
Email : <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><div id='ema'></div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = initialise();

function initialise() {
    username = document.getElementById('username');
    username.addEventListener('keyup', respond, false);
    email = document.getElementById('email');
    email.addEventListener('keyup', respond, false);
}

function respond(e) {
    //code
    alert(e.target.id);
}
```